# What is the general solution to equations of form $f(k\cdot x)-lf(x)=1, k,l \in \Bbb N$ ? Prove that $\log_{10} x$ is the solution when $k = 10,l =1$.

Tags: functions, logarithms

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following equation:
$$f(10\cdot x)-f(x)=1 \quad\quad (1)$$

From looking at this equation I can easily see that $f(x)=\log_{10}(x)$ works out nicely.

However, if the equation would have been 
$$f(10\cdot x)-5f(x)=1 \quad\quad (2)$$
then the logarithm would not have worked out.

Two questions:

1. How can I prove that the logarithm is the only solution to equation (1)?
2. Is there a general way to solve these kind of equations, for example, how would one solve equation (2)?

Comment: Do you require your function to be continuous? If not I suspect that logarithm might not be the only solution to (1).

Comment: No, does not have to be continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question, $\log_{10}$ is not the only solution: let $g$ be any function defined on $[1, 10)$. Define
$$f(x) = k + g(x \cdot 10 ^{-k})$$
when $10^k \le x \lt 10^{k+1}$. Then $f$ is a solution of the functional equation. Note that $k = \lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor$

For the second equation, you can use a similar definition, I suggest
$$f(x) = 5^k \left( g(x \cdot 10 ^{-k}) + \frac{1}{4}\right) - \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: What exactly is your k? The integer part of the log or what does this notation mean? Okay, its clearer now!

Comment: It is the floor function of the $\log_{10}(x)$.

Comment: I guess you found this solution by a mixture of "educated guess" and trying a few things out. I believe that there is no more general way to solve this kind of equations?

Comment: The point is I don't know what is "this kind of equations". Here, for a given $x$, if you define $u_n = f(10^n x)$, you see that the relation reduces to a recurrence relation $u_{n+1} = u_{n} + 1$ or $u_{n+1} = 5 u_{n} + 1$. You can use your knowledge about numerical sequences to solve this: if you know one term, you know the whole sequence. Then it only remains to realize that only one of the $10^n x$ is in the interval $[1, 10)$.

Comment: Okay, good point. I guess my question is also: Is there a name for equations that contain not only the variable but also the function? A bit like a differential equation, just without derivatives but possibly non-linear terms of $f$ or shifted arguments $f(x-k)$ or additional factors $c\cdot f(k\cdot x)$ with some parameters $k$ and $c$

Comment: Yes, the name is *[functional equation](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=functional%20equation)*. There is indeed no universal approach.

Answer (score 2):

As Gribouillis points out, there are no unique solutions to equations like this.
The equation only connects the values of $f(x)$ for values of $x$ that differ by factor ten, so it says nothing about $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ when $x/y$ is not an integer power of ten.

However, there is a way to find a "nice" solution to the kind of equation.
If you want the general solution instead of pretty ones, this is not your answer.
By pretty I mean something that satisfies a natural generalization of your condition.

Consider the second problem.
Take any $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.
We have
$$
\begin{split}
f(10^nx)
&=
1+5f(10^{n-1}x)
\\&=
1+5(1+5f(10^{n-2}x))
\\&=
(1+5)+5^2f(10^{n-2}x)
\\&=
\dots
\\&=
(1+5+25+\dots+5^{n-1})+5^nf(x)
\\&=
\frac14(5^n-1)+5^nf(x)
\\&=
5^n(\frac14+f(x))-\frac14
.
\end{split}
$$
This formula can be used to find the general solution if you want to.
To find a pretty solution, we add the *additional restricting assumption* that this holds for all values of $n\in\mathbb R$.
For $x=1$ and $f(1)=a-1/4$ (the shift is for convenience) this leads to
$$
f(y)
=
f(10^{\log_{10}y})
=
%5^{\log_{10}y}(\frac14+a)-\frac14
5^{\log_{10}y}a-\frac14
.
$$
It is easy to check that this indeed satisfies
$f(10^tx)
%=5^{t+\log_{10}x}a-\frac14=5^t5^{\log_{10}x}a-\frac14
=5^t(f(x)+1/4)-1/4$
for all $x>0$ and $t\in\mathbb R$.

You are free to choose the parameter $a$.
For $a=0$ you get the constant function $f(x)=-1/4$.

Similarly, for the first problem you would get $f(y)=a+\log_{10}y$ with this method.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(10\cdot x)-f(x)=1 \quad\quad (1)$$

By induction it's easy to prove $ f(10^n) = n + f(1) $

So any function $g(s) \longrightarrow g(1) +  \log_{10} $(s) satisfy $(1)$

With $ s \ne 0 $ ....

Comment: For the first equation, it is indeed easy to see that if $f(x)$ is a solution, then  $f(x) + C$ is a solution for any constant $C$.